# Air: Packaging application for Google Android take to long

Tags: android, air

I build flash application for Android, I am trying to run it over air emulator and it works just fine, trying to run it over device or export release build(apk) and it takes for ever. I been able to wait 2 hours before I fores stop the Flash Builder.

I wasn't been able to produce the APK. Any ideas what to do? What should I test?

Technical data:

- My PC: Win 7 4 GB Ram, 2.5 GHZ
- Flash builder 4.7
- Devices: Sony Ericsson, HTC sensation, Assus tablet and another few...

Comment: It shouldn't take much longer than running in an emulator. What does the 'progress' tab (usually next 'console') say? Does it compile if you try to make a release build? Do you get the export release build dialog? What I'm trying to say is, please provide more info in order to get help. :-)

Comment: @jpop The progress bar stacks at "packaging application for android", in both of the cases.